# Backend service with SOAP binding required to expose as a RESTful - WSO2 ESB

Tags: rest, soap, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

What I'm trying to do is as follows,

Business use-case : A backend service with SOAP binding required to expose as a RESTful service. Consumers require to get the responses from JSON using the same API.

[image]

I have gone through below links but didn't find them useful. Configurations are either not given or not working.

http://asanka.abeysinghe.org/2013/05/implementing-api-facade-with-wso2-api.html

[WSO2 API Manager convert SOAP to REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14505070/wso2-api-manager-convert-soap-to-rest)

[WSO2 API Manager - can it convert REST requests to SOAP requests on the backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12061650/wso2-api-manager-can-it-convert-rest-requests-to-soap-requests-on-the-backend)

I know the step what to be done but what I'm wondering is how that should be done in the ESB. Exact configurations.

Backend service with SOAP binding required to expose as a RESTful - WSO2 ESB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to expose a SOAP Service and REST (POX or JSON), you can do it using ESB. You can create a API in ESB and does the mapping between JSON or POX to SOAP. There are samples available in the ESB documentation. Please check from [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Using+REST).  You do not need a API manager,  if you just need to expose some REST API.  You can do it using ESB as well and you do not need to use API Manager.

Comment: Could you please post the configurations? That's what I'm looking for. Is it a common one or based on API?

Comment: It is based on your requirement.  There are sample and you want to modify it according to your SOAP BE.  I guess best thing is to try out a sample and see.